# DHCP server ignoring DHCP requests

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-server

My DHCP server is ignoring DHCP request from specific client. Using tcpdump in my host controller (where DHCP is served from) I can see the requests

```
21:50:12.909484 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 1319, offset 0, flags [none], 
proto UDP (17), length 336)
    169.254.33.8.bootpc > 255.255.255.255.bootps: [udp sum ok] 
BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 20:b0:f7:04:36:f0 (oui Unknown), length 308, 
xid 0x5851f42d, Flags [none] (0x0000)
      Client-Ethernet-Address 20:b0:f7:04:36:f0 (oui Unknown)
      Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
    Magic Cookie 0x63825363
    DHCP-Message Option 53, length 1: Discover
    MSZ Option 57, length 2: 1486
    Parameter-Request Option 55, length 4: 
      Subnet-Mask, Default-Gateway, BR, Domain-Name-Server
    END Option 255, length 0
    PAD Option 0, length 0, occurs 54
```

It seems that I am only able to offer this client an address if it's ip is 0.0.0.0 but not 169.254.33.8

My interface file like this

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.78.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

and my udhcpd.conf looks like:

```
# The start and end of the IP lease block
start   10.78.0.2
end     10.78.0.200

# The interface that udhcpd will use
interface    eth0

opt dns 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 #public google dns servers
option  subnet  255.255.255.0
opt router      10.78.0.1

option  lease   864000      # default: 10 days
# Arbitrary option in hex form:
option  0x08    01020304    # option 8: "cookie server IP addr: 1.2.3.4"
```

I am not sure what the problem is here. Can you guys give me some ideas?

Comment: 169 addresses are APIPA addresses. It's automatically assigning itself that address because it cannot get a routable IP address. You probably need to investigate that client, rather than the server.

Comment: The client assigns itself the APIPA address because my dhcp server starts a little late. But why can't the dhcp server assign it when it gets the request later.